# chromium headless ozone build on linux x86_64 failed

Tags: linux, chromium, headless, ozone

I'm trying to perform an GN buld on Linux. and i get the folloging error:

obj/content/browser/browser/browser_main_loop.o:../../content/browser/browser_main_loop.cc:function content::BrowserMainLoop::PreMainMessageLoopRun(): error: undefined reference to 'views::WindowManagerConnection::Create(mojo::ApplicationImpl*)'

my Settings are:
is_debug = false
is_component_build = true

use_ozone=true
ozone_auto_platforms=false
ozone_platform_headless=true
is_headless=true
toolkit_views=false